# Is use of PageView web part poses a security risk?

Tags: security, page-viewer-web-part

I have two internal web applications in same domain,  I want to integrate them within sharepoint using a PageView webpart. Some how the security community of the organization believes it would increase the risk and make it insecure as PageView is based on iFrame. Is it really true that use of PageView is not secure.